Regarding the proof of $R$ is noetherian if and only if every finitely generated $R$-module is noetherian.

$R$ is noetherian if and only if every finitely generated $R$-module is noetherian.

$\Longleftarrow:$ If every finitely generated $R$-module is noetherian, then $R$ is a finitely generated $R$-module, thus every submodule of $R$ is finitely generated(i.e. every ideal of $R$ is finitely generated).
$\Longrightarrow$: If $R$ is noetherian and $M=\langle u_1,\ldots,u_n\rangle$ is a finitely generated $R$-module, then consider the map $\tau: R^n\to M$ defined by $$\tau(r_1,\ldots,r_n)=r_1u_1+\ldots+r_nu_n$$
Let $S$ be a submodule of $M$. Then $\tau^{-1}(S)=\{u\in R^n|\tau(u)\in S\}$ is a submodule of $R^n$, and  finitely generated if every submdoule of $R^n$ is finitely generated. Say, $\tau^{-1}(S)=\langle v_1,\ldots,v_k\rangle$, then $S$ is finitely generated by $\{\tau(v_1),\ldots,\tau(v_k)\}$. Hence, we only need to prove that every submodule $S$ of $R^n$ is finitely generated. If $n=1$, then $M$ is an ideal of $R$, and thus finitely generated by definition. Assume that every submodule of $R^k$ is finitely generated for all $1\leq k<n$ and let $S$ be a submodule of $R^n$. If $n>1$, let $$S_1=\{(0,\ldots,0,a_n)|(a_1,\ldots,a_{n-1},a_n)\in S\}$$ $S_1$ is isomorphic to an ideal of $R$ and thus finitely generated, say $S_1=\langle \mathcal{G}_1\rangle$, where $\mathcal{G}_1=\{g_1,\ldots,g_k\}$ is a finite subset of $S_1$. Let $$S_2=\{v\in S| v=(a_1,\ldots,a_{n-1},0),a_1,\ldots,a_{n-1}\in R\}$$which is isomorphic to a submodule of $R^{n-1}$, thus $S_2$ is finitely generated, say $S_2=\langle \mathcal{G}_2\rangle$, where $\mathcal{G}_2$ is a finite subset of $S$. Each $g_i\in \mathcal{G}_2$ has the form $$g_i=(0,\ldots,0,g_{i,n})$$ and there is a $\overline{g_i}$ of the form $$\overline{g_i}=(g_{i,1},\ldots,g_{i,n-1},g_{i,n})$$ Let $\overline{\mathcal{G}_1}=\{\overline{g_1},\ldots,\overline{g_k}\}$. We claim that $S$ is generated by $\overline{\mathcal{G}_1}\cup \mathcal{G}_2$.
Let $v=(a_1,\ldots,a_n)\in S$. Then $$(0,\ldots,0,a_n)=\sum_{i=1}^kr_ig_i$$ Now, consider the sum $w=\sum_{i=1}^kr_i\overline{g_i}$. Thus, $$v=(v-w)+w$$ Hence, $$v=(v-w)+w\in \langle \mathcal{G}_2\rangle+\langle \overline{\mathcal{G}_1}\rangle=\langle \overline{\mathcal{G}_1}\cup \mathcal{G}_2 \rangle $$ as desired.
Question:
Why we need $\overline{\mathcal{G}_1}$ instead of just $\mathcal{G}_1$? If we write $(0,0,\ldots,0,a_n)$ as $w=\sum_{i=1}^kr_ig_i$, then we can deduce that $v=(v-w)+w\in \langle \mathcal{G}_1\cup \mathcal{G}_2\rangle$. Where am I wrong? Thank you for your help.

The set $S_1$ is (in general) not a subset of $S$, so the elements of $G_1$ are not in $S$.

@AndrewHubery Get your idea! Thank you!
